# Insert array values into random positions of another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
a = ["Fruit", "Emu", "Color"]
b = ["Banana", "Name", "Orange"]
```

I want to insert `b` array values into  random positions of `a`. A possible output for these two arrays would be:

```
c = ["Banana", "Fruit", "Emu", "Color", "Orange", "Name"]
```

Here, `b` array values are inserted into `a`, but the value sequence

> `"Fruit"` → `"Emu"` → `"Color"`

of `a` is not hampered. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show us your efforts.

Comment: @Зелёный, I haven't done anything yet. I assume that I can do it using a  `brute force` **loop** approach, but I want to know if there is anything in ruby to do this easily.

Comment: In other words, i don't want to try something, write code for me.

Comment: @Зелёный, If you think that's what I want, then don't bother to write code for me. :) . Thanks.

Comment: @Зелёный (I hope I pronounced that correctly), I've never understood demands for OPs to show failed code.  If it solicits a response, the code produced is generally artificial, particularly if the OP doesn't really know where to begin. It's also smacks of elitism, as high-rep (and not so high-rep) askers are *never* asked to produce code. If the question is clear, and not stupid, that's enough for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [:foo, :bar, :baz]

b.each_with_object(a.dup) { |e, ary| ary.insert(rand(0..ary.size), e) }
#=> [:baz, 1, 2, :foo, :bar, 3]
```

- [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) creates a copy of `a` that is passed as `ary` into the block, along with each of `b`'s elements
- [`rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) returns a random index between `0` (beginning of array) and `ary.size` (end of array)
- [`insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-insert) inserts the current element at the given index
- [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) returns the copied array with the randomly inserted elements

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. You're just awesome. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
def stuff_randomly(a,b)
  sz_a  = a.size
  cpy_a = a.dup
  (sz_a+b.size).times.to_a.shuffle.map do |i|
    (i < sz_a) ? cpy_a.shift : b[i-sz_a]
  end
end

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
10.times { p stuff_randomly(a,b) }
[:foo, 1, 2, 3, :bar, :baz]
[1, :baz, 2, :foo, 3, :bar]
[1, :foo, :bar, :baz, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, :foo, :bar, :baz]
[1, :bar, :foo, 2, 3, :baz]
[:foo, 1, :baz, 2, :bar, 3]
[:bar, 1, 2, 3, :foo, :baz]
[:bar, 1, :foo, :baz, 2, 3]
[1, 2, :baz, :bar, :foo, 3]
[1, :foo, :bar, 2, 3, :baz]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is below.

```
a = ["Fruit", "Emu", "Color"]
b = ["Banana", "Name", "Orange"]

b.each { |value| a.insert(rand(0..a.length), value) }

#=> ["Name", "Orange", "Fruit", "Emu", "Banana", "Color"]
```

For each element of `b`, insert the value into a random index of `a`.

This is essentially the answer from [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31828252/4482286), but without the `each_with_object` method. I think it's slightly cleaner this way and provides the same solution.

Comment: That will modify `a`. The whole purpose of `each_with_object` is to return a new hash.

Comment: I see. I missed that the result was supposed to be returned in a new array.